# How to access columns in a dataframe having name with special character

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe with column names which contains special characters like

```
Date    
('Date','') 
('Max_Bid_Price', 'ALBAN')
```

The problem is when i am trying to drop ('Date','') columns it is throwing error.

I tried

```
df["('Date','')"]   # not able to find the label
df["\(\'Date\'\,\'\'\)"] # not able to find the label
```

but when i tried

```
data.columns[1] # i got the column value as output
data.drop(data.columns[1],axis=0) # but it still throws an error: "labels [('Date', '')] not contained in axis"
```

Can anyone help me how to access those columns with name(since i have to do operations on it) and also drop those columns:

Comment: df['(\'Date\',\'\')']. Does that work?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Why do the names end up like that in the first place? According to what you wrote, that first attempt should work. The second snippet fails because of the incorrect axis parameter, you should read the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [*raw string literals*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals):

```
df.drop(r"('Date','')", axis=1)
```

Comment: How is it different than ```df.drop("('Date','')", axis=1)```? It's literally the same outcome...

Comment: You are right, in this situation the `r` is not adding anything, as it works on 'backslash'.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to drop a column, the axis should be 1

```
data.drop(data.columns[1],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop is not in place I'm afraid:

```py
df=df.drop("('Date','')", axis=1)
```

Alternatively:

```py
df=df.drop(columns="('Date','')")
```